# Deploy Scully Static Folder with angular-cli-ghpages?

Tags: angular, github-pages, angular-cli-ghpages, scully, scullyio

[Scully](https://scully.io/) generates the project to `project/dist/static`.

How do we deploy that instead of `project/dist/project-name` with [angular-cli-ghpages](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-cli-ghpages)?

Comment: https://github.com/angular-schule/angular-cli-ghpages/issues/115

Answer (score 1):

if you want to deploy your scully static site on github pages, the easiest way is to use this Github action:

https://github.com/marketplace/actions/scully-publish

Here is an example of how to use it:

https://github.com/d-koppenhagen/d-koppenhagen.de/blob/master/.github/workflows/nodejs.yml#L21-L25